# How to dynamically append a bootstrap modal to a body using javascript

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap model like below, I want to insert this modal to every html page by calling a javascript function addModal(); and it should append the modal to the body tag 
how to do it

```html
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: do you want to add the modal when the page is loading?

Comment: yes, but it should come from javascript using function call, so that i will add the js file to every page and call the function and it will append the modal to that page

Comment: and your file is html not php right? If it was php you wouldn't even need a function: `<?php require_once "your_modal.html"; ?>`

Comment: no actuly i want that modal to come from js file. and it is html pages not php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. Now this way you just have to link your js file and then call the function. (you'll still need jquery for the `.append()` method)

```
function addModal() {
  $("body").append('<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
  </div>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way of doing this is using jquery:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#ModalDiv").load("yourModal.html");
   });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body>

   //your code

   <div id="ModalDiv"></div>

   //your code

</body>
```

Comment: i'm not having your-modal.htm i want to add that modal from js file

Comment: i want to append that modal div to body tag